# ButterKnife 8.0.1 @OnClick not working in Fragment - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, butterknife

I am using ButterKnife 8.0.1 in my android studio project. Below is my gradle file and snippet of fragment class. I am unable to see Toast message in button click. But I am able to see Toast if I use onCLicklistener .

Please help me find out what I am doing wrong I am stuck

My Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tdd.serveroverload.com.tdd"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
}
```

Fragment class

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View calcView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        calcView.findViewById(R.id.add).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 //It Works
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, calcView);

        return calcView;
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.one)
    public void one(View view) {

         //It Does not Works
        if (view.getId() == R.id.one) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        result.setText(result.getText().toString() + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Can't you see `Click` or `working` toast ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Butterknife github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download) page:

> Add this to you project-level build.gradle:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>   repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>    }
>   dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Add this to your module-level build.gradle:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'android-apt'
>
> android {
>   ...
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
>   apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
> }
> ```
>
> Make sure the line `apply plugin ...` is placed somewhere at the top
> of the file.

Comment: Thanks I did it but now I am getting crash

 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for tdd.serveroverload.com.tdd.ui.fragment.HomeFragment
                                                                                at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:189)
 at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:167) at tdd.serveroverload.com.tdd.ui.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:85)

Comment: It solved all my problem thanks MidasLefko for help.

Comment: My pleasure I ran into the same issue when I upgraded from 7.0.1 to 8.0.1

Answer (score 1):

To bind click event on fragment view :

You just need to add an annotation. No need to check id using a view.

Please update your code as below :

```
 @OnClick(R.id.one)
    public void one() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        result.setText(result.getText().toString() + 1);
    }
```

Here is sample code from below demo :

```
    /**
     * Attempts to call below method when 'Fragment Binding Button' get clicked.
     */
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_fragment_binding)
    void OnFragmentBindingClicked() {
        loadSampleFragment();
    }
```

For more information and different binding please check below demo :

https://github.com/mamatagelanee07/ButterKnifeDemo

Comment: I know adding id is optional but it was not working without it so I started trying with id,  you can see second toast I had added .

Answer (score 1):

```
App Level(build.gradle)

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}


Project Level(build.gradle)

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same website https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download
Please add same below

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}
```