# ButterKnife 8.6.0 not working

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, butterknife

I was previously using 7.0.1 it was working fine but suddenly it stop working, giving null pointer exception while using variables.Then i change it to 8.6.0

My code is like this.

(project gradle)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.6.0'    
}
```

(app gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
```

Inside Fragment

```
public class ScheduleRideFragment extends Fragment {
@BindView(R.id.scheduleRideFragApplyCouponButton)
Button applyCouponButton;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.schedule_ride_fragment_layout, null);
    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    initAndSetListners();
    return view; 
}
private void initAndSetListners() {
applyCouponButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
 }
}
```

but it giving java.lang.NullPointerException(see the log)
[image]

Note: I have posted the related code only

i have also look these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672516/butterknife-8-0-1-onclick-not-working-in-fragment-android-studio),[2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/588),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126066/butterknife-fragment-button-not-working) answers but don't work
it is happening Both case (Fragment and activity) am i doing somthing wrong ?

I **can't Post** whole schedule_ride_fragment_layout.xml code so i am posting related code only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/scheduleRideCouponButtonContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:visibility="invisible">
<Button
android:id="@+id/scheduleRideFragApplyCouponButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="35sp"
android:background="@color/brightGreen"
android:ems="12"
android:text="APPLY COUPON"
android:textColor="@color/textColor" /></LinearLayout></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

Comment: Try with this `LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout. schedule_ride_fragment_layout, container, false)`

Comment: thnks for reply @Luca Nicoletti but it did't work

Comment: please post schedule_ride_fragment_layout.xml

Comment: @ lelloman is you asking for button ID, I have check that R.id.scheduleRideFragApplyCouponButton exists into xml. It was working fine before two day, i did,t change anything

Comment: yes you're right, did you do a clean build after upgrading the library?

Comment: Yes i did that , infact also try Invalidate and restart

Comment: Is there somthing wrong with BuuterKnife lib.. if you see the log(image posted) there is log of ButterKnife-"Not found. Trying superclass android.support.v4.app.Fragment"????

Comment: Can you post `R.layout.schedule_ride_fragment_layout` also?

Comment: @azizbekian just replied in comment above, i am sure, R.id.scheduleRideFragApplyCouponButton  is there

Comment: use this inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_rule_fragment_layout, container, false); to inflate

Comment: @ Deepak Chethan already try this ,It was also suggested by @ Luca Nicoletti

Answer (score 3):

Starting from **Butterknife 8.6.0**:

***Remove classpath plugin*** in **build.gradle** from **(project gradle)**

```
dependencies {
       classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.6.0'
}
```

***And only keep the following dependencies*** in **build.gradle** from **(app gradle)**  as mentioned in the [official documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Finally for **onClickListener()** use the **OnClick** annotation provided by Butterknife,

```
@OnClick(R.id.scheduleRideFragApplyCouponButton)
public void onApplyCouponButtonClick(Button button){
}
```

Comment: Sir, what's the significant difference between your code and OP's code? What's the problem with OP's code that your code solves?

Comment: @Prokash Sarkar also try this, but initialy its not giving error, there are some field also like TextView and EditText ,some error is comming on them,i am wondered if it was working from last 2 months why it stop working.

Comment: Please post the code for your xml layout too @AjeetChoudhary

Comment: Actually, he's keeping dependency plugins which aren't recommended by the official documentation.  I suspect there's might be a dependency confliction. @azizbekian

Comment: I think we are using same dependencies, still it not works

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary you need to remove the "classpath" and only keep "compile" + "annotationProcessor" dependencies. Rest of the part should be the same.